# Issue with Updating Database After Uploading a File

Tags: php, mysql, database, file-upload

I am trying to upload the file and then insert the file name into the database.

Below is my code:

```
<?php
//connecting to database
session_start();
include('/applications/MAMP/htdocs/connect.php');
$u = $_SESSION['username'];


if (!empty($_FILES)) {
$file = $_FILES['Filedata'];

    $tempFile = $_FILES['Filedata']['tmp_name'];
    $targetPath = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . $_REQUEST['folder'] . '/';
    $targetFile =  str_replace('//','/',$targetPath) . $_FILES['Filedata']['name'];

    // $fileTypes  = str_replace('*.','',$_REQUEST['fileext']);
    // $fileTypes  = str_replace(';','|',$fileTypes);
    // $typesArray = split('\|',$fileTypes);
    // $fileParts  = pathinfo($_FILES['Filedata']['name']);

    // if (in_array($fileParts['extension'],$typesArray)) {
        // Uncomment the following line if you want to make the directory if it doesn't exist
        // mkdir(str_replace('//','/',$targetPath), 0755, true);
        $n = $file['name'];
        move_uploaded_file($tempFile,$targetFile);
        echo str_replace($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'],'',$targetFile);
        mysqli_select_db($connect,"people");
$i = "update users set filelocation = '$n' where sessionusername = '$u'";
$q = mysqli_query($connect,$i);
    // } else {
    //  echo 'Invalid file type.';
    // }
}


?>
```

The file is being uploaded successfully, but the name is not getting updated in the database.

Please help me.

Comment: Where do you define the variable `$u`? And could you post your database structure?

Answer (score 2):

`$n = $file['name']`; will return nothing since $file is not declared anywhere. You probably want to use:

```
$n = $_FILES['Filedata']['name'];
```

or anything else declared you really want to put in your DB ;-)

Comment: `$_FILES['Filedata']['name']` gives him only temp name of file, he need `$targetFile`

Comment: Nope, you're describing $_FILES['Filedata']['tmp_name'] but indeed $targetFile contains the full manipulated path. Anyway, there's no need to declare a new variable here, $targetFile could be used in the query, plus it's manipulated again after $n declaration.

Comment: @Dobiatowski: That is not correct. The temporary name of the file is stored in `$_FILES['Filedata']['tmp_name']`.

Comment: I need the name of the file...what should I finally use? BTW , $file has been declared

Comment: @sarthaksss if you only need name use `$_FILES['Filedata']['name']` if you want full path use `$targetFile`, @MichielPater - you have right

Comment: Ah, this code is so badly written and formatted I hadn't even seen it! `print $i` and `print mysqli_error()` after the query to see if it succeeds

Comment: @sarthaksss: Yes, `$file` has been declared, but in order to get the filename you will need to use something different than `$_FILES['Filedata']`. I would advise to use the answer of Capsule.

Comment: @michiel Thanks...I'll just try that and let you knoww.

Comment: @sarthaksss you have to learn to debug when it doesn't work. Please apply my advices: check what your SQL query really is by printing $i and check if there's no SQL error by printing mysqli_error() after the query. You could also check if $q return true (query succeeded) or false (there's something wrong, check for errors)

Comment: @capsule I did what you suggessted, and If it use to set filelocation as 'whoa', it works..but $n does not work...plz help me..genius

Comment: echo $n, does not display anything.

Comment: $q returns true...but $n displays nothing, which means not an issue with sql.

Comment: I am getting a message that says undefine variable $n.

Comment: Try $targetFile instead of $n in your query then, if your file move works, then $targetFile is defined, for sure

Comment: another question, should I place the db code inside the if or outside it?

Answer (score 0):

you have `$n = $file['name'];`

it should be `$n = $targetFile`

But first of all - clean your code ;)

I cleaned up it for you. Check if this work.

```
<?php
session_start();
include('/applications/MAMP/htdocs/connect.php');
mysqli_select_db("people");

if (!isset($_REQUEST['folder'])) $_REQUEST['folder'] = "";

if (!empty($_FILES)) {
    $tempFile = $_FILES['Filedata']['tmp_name'];
    $targetPath = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . $_REQUEST['folder'] . '/';
    $targetFile =  str_replace('//','/',$targetPath) . $_FILES['Filedata']['name'];

    move_uploaded_file($tempFile,$targetFile);
    $i = "UPDATE users SET filelocation = '$targetFile' WHERE sessionusername = '{$_SESSION['username']}'";
    $q = mysqli_query($i);

    //debug
    echo "$targetFile<br/>
        $tempFile<br/>
        $i<br/>";
    echo mysqli_error();
}
else {
    echo "No file";
}
?>
```

Comment: hey $n = $targetFile does not work...The database remins the same.

Comment: if i echo those two, nothing is being displayed.

Comment: the file gets uploaded successfully, but the name does not change.. $u also matches the database.

Comment: @dobiatowski can you help me out??